# Constant NSString release

Tags: nsstring

```
NSString *string = @"hello";
```

1) I keep reading that constant NSString does not get released, but this Apple page mentions:

> the compiler makes such object
>   constants unique on a per-module
>   basis, and they’re never deallocated,
>   though you can retain and release them
>   as you do any other object.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html

2) If constant NSString does not get released, would it cause memory problems if used extensively? For example, is this a problem if repeated thousands of times:

```
NSString *string = @"One";
...
string = @"two";
...
string = @"three";
...
```

what's a good alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Constant strings are part of you app's binary.

So, you do not need to worry about memory management, as they exist through all the execution and can not be released.